Is serialized mode possible with Microsoft.Data.Sqlite?
Due to migrating my Xamarin.iOS application to .NET 8 I moved from Mono.Data.Sqlite to Microsoft.Data.Sqlite version 8.0.4. The SqlConnection seems to not support (at least by default) the serialized mode to avoid multithreading issues.
Serialized mode is common for mobile applications. Is it supported on Microsoft.Data.Sqlite? If not, is there an alternative for .NET 8? There is no API exposed to set the config mode to serialised.

This is not unexpected, honestly. The normal and expected usage of any ADO.NET connection, by any provider, is: sequential access only, concurrent access is undefined, with it being your job (as the caller) to serialize access on a single connection. It wouldn't actually be that much work to write a decorator layer for ADO.NET that provides this (I've written multiple ADO.NET decorators - it is verbose and ugly, but not technically difficult), but the nature of the data-reader API, plus the reality of potentially async access means that you'd need to use a mutex or semaphore rather than just a
lock.
If all of your data access code is in one place, then a much simpler option would be to add the synchronization at that layer.
But no: I would not pin your hopes on finding another library that implements a very unusual and atypical API behaviour. Instead, I would change your code to use ADO.NET in the expected way.
